# Having trouble in typescript generic type declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm creating a hook called `useUpdate`, having trouble declaring the type, the code shows below

```js
type CallBack<T extends readonly any[]> = (
  ...args: T
) => void | (() => void | undefined);

function useUpdate<T extends readonly any[]>(
  callback: CallBack<T>,
  deps: T
) {
  const didMount = useRef(false);
  const prevDeps = useRef(deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didMount.current) {
      didMount.current = true;

      return;
    }

    const clean = callback(...prevDeps.current);

    prevDeps.current = deps;

    return () => {
      if (clean) {
        clean();
      }
    };
  }, deps);
}
```

when using it there's no problem if the callback has args, but if no args is provided for the callback, the type of deps will be incorrect

```js
const state: boolean = useSomethingElse(); // get changable data from anywere else

// OK, no type error
useUpdate((prevState) => {
 console.log('I want to compare the current state and prevState', prevState, state);
},[state]);


useUpdate(() => {
 console.log('I only care about the current state', state);
},[state]); // Type error occurs on this line, the message is:
//  Argument of type '[boolean]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.
//  Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0.ts(2345)
```

I know it's because TypeScript sets the T as callback args which is [] if the args are not provided, but is there any way to let TypeScript uses the type of deps and skips the type of callback args while setting the T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways you can fix this:

(1) Make `deps` the first parameter so it starts by inferring `T` from `deps`

(2) Use a second generic for `callback`:

```
function useUpdate<T extends readonly any[], Cb extends CallBack<T>>(
  callback: Cb,
  deps: T
) {
```